# Trying to write a function to display the time in a 12 hour format but the HTML is not displaying the time and the function returns null

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have an assignment where we have to plugin the time in a 12 hour format through a function in a js file. I have the function written but the HTML is not picking it up and the function is returning a null value.

If I layout the function between script tags in the HTML file it will return the time fine but I need it to be styled for the assignment and also it has to be in a separate js file.

```
/*here is the js file*/
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
     //GET CURRENT DATE-TIME
  var currentTime = new Date ();

  //GET THE CURRENT TIME
  var hours = currentTime.getHours ();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes ();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds ();

  //APPEND A ZERO(0) IF MINUTES OR SECONDS ARE LESS THAN 10
  minutes = ( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes;
  seconds = ( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds;

  //CHOOSE AM IF HOUR IS LESS THAN 12 AND PM IF HOUR IS BIGGER THAN 12
  var ampm = ( hours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

  //CHANGE TO 12 HOUR FORMAT BY SUBTRACTING 12 IF HOUR IS BIGGER THAN 12.
  hours = ( hours > 12 ) ? hours - 12 : hours;

  //CHANGE HOUR OF 0 (MIDNIGHT) TO 12.
  hours = ( hours == 0 ) ? 12 : hours;

  //CREATE STRING OF TIME
  var currentTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + ampm;

  //DISPLAY TIME IN DIV
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
var displayCurrentTime = $("minutes");
console.log(displayCurrentTime);

var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
    if (num < 10) { return "0" + num; }
    else { return num; }
};

window.onload = function() {
    // set initial clock display and then set interval timer to display
    // new time every second. Don't store timer object because it 
    // won't be needed - clock will just run.
    displayCurrentTime(setInterval(1000));
};
```

There are 4 span ids in the HTML file (hours, minutes, seconds, and ampm) that need to be filled.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Digital clock</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Clock</legend>
            <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
            <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
        </fieldset>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("clock")` You define a function to handle this at the top of the file, should use it here

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Nothing displays in the index.html at all. For some reason I cannot get it to connect to the span ids. There are 4 of them hours, minutes, secons, and ampm.

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant parts of the HTML? Currently you seem to be trying to update an element which is the child of the `#clock` element, and that doesn't match the 4 spans you're talking about

Comment: I have updated the html code

Comment: `var displayCurrentTime = $("minutes");` where is the *$* function defined?

Comment: That is more for debugging purposes but the minutes variable is defined inside of the function. I just don't know how to get it out to return it to the HTML file. I am confused because the problem wants them all separately but the assignment only tells me to write one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues that I see that would be tripping you up

1) You defined your function as `displayCurrentTime` (which works), but then overwrite it completly with the line `var displayCurrentTime = $("minutes")`. So, instead of calling a function,  you're going to retrieve an element 
- *Your console.log() is right after, so that's why you're seeing a null value*

2) You say "4 span ids in the HTML file (hours, minutes, seconds, and ampm) that need to be filled" but your script just returns all of those fields, joined together - that's not helpful to you, but you do have all the correct values already in the function

```
var displayCurrentTime = function() {
  var currentTime = new Date ();

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  minutes = ( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes;
  seconds = ( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds;

  var ampm = ( hours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

  hours = ( hours > 12 ) ? hours - 12 : hours;
  hours = ( hours == 0 ) ? 12 : hours;

  // At this point, all 4 values are ready to drop into your span tags
  $('hours').textContent = hours;
  $('minutes').textContent = minutes;
  $('seconds').textContent = seconds;
  $('ampm').textContent = ampm;
}
```

3) Your setInterval is being called wrong, it should be like

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
};
```

[Here is the codepen with these changes](https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/zYYoyLR)

Comment: error "textContent is not a function at displayCurrentTime" am I expected to write ($('ampm').textContent(ampm);) differently?

Comment: No, that's me being too used to jQuery and not thinking - I'll fix that right now

Comment: I tried nodeValue too, but this is useful since we are going to start our jQuery unit next week

Comment: jQuery is fantastic, and overused as hell so there's a ton of resources to learn from online and here ( You'll see most answers to javascript / HTML using jQuery ). But yeah, `.textContent = text`, not `.textContent(text)`

Comment: Hooray! I was stuck on this forever. Thank you so much. Now I understand that you have to call them inside the function for the span tags not outside of the function.

Comment: Yeah, might want to have a quick read of [this article](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/understanding-hoisting-and-scoping-in-javascript-39ea7b41e31) if you want to understand scoping more - Which is the issue you're talking about, of the variable only being defined inside the function

Comment: Awesome! I will keep that around for sure, that's a good article. Appreciate all of the help

Comment: Re "*You'll see most answers to javascript / HTML using jQuery*", no you wont. Searching using [\[javascript\]\[html\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+html) shows only 7 jQuery tags in the first 50 questions. That may change depending on when the search is run, but it won't change much.